# Using selectors for callbacks?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates

I think i should be using selectors (or even a different paradigm), but even after R'ing TFM I can't figure out what i'm supposed to do. It's all related to callbacks from a delegate

I have my main Model object:

```
    @implementation Model
    @synthesize myConnection; // which is an NSURLConnection
    ...
    -(void)someMethod{
    MyConnectionDelegate *mcd = [[MyConnectionDelegate alloc]initWithCallingObject:self];
    myConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:requestForToken delegate:mcd];
...
}
-(void)didGetCalledBack:(NSArray *)resultArray{
  NSLog(@"got the callback");
}
```

and then in my delegate:

```
@implementation MyConnectionDelegate
@synthesize callingObject; // which is of type id
@synthesize resultArray; // NSArray
-(id)initWithCallingObject:(id)caller{
  ...//std [self init] block
  self.callingObject  = caller;
  return self;
...
}


-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
...
}
//and all the other NSURLConnection delegate methods


- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
  ...
  // finish building array of results into self.resultArray
  [self.callingObject didGetCalledBack:self.resultArray];
}
```

So...
1) I think i should be using selectors, or something else rather than hardcoding the fact that the caller (delegator?) needs to implement -`didGetCalledBack`: 
Right? IF so, how? (and why, other than cleanliness)

2) Or is my whole implementation wrong in the way i'm attempting to use a callback from the delegate of the `NSURLConnection` back to the delegator wrong?

I've looked at the Apple samplecode etc but nothing i've seen ever has anything other than `delegate:self`.  Maybe i should have delegate:self too for the `NSURLConnection`, but I'm making many connections and if i do delegate:self my delegate methods (like -`didReceiveData`:) become a big mess of `if (connection ==connection1){` type code.

thanks,
richard

Comment: I think that making the connection from Model but implementing the delegate elsewhere unnecessarily spreads related code over different classes, making it hard to maintain and difficult to understand. 
If you have many delegates there, then your Model probably does too much, i.e. things that belong somewhere else *completely*.

Comment: I don't fundamentally disagree, but if i don't use delegates elsewhere then my 5-6 REST calls each returning XML would end up with those big if/elseif statements in my 6 NSXMLParser delegate methods and 5-6 NSURLConnection delegate methods.  That's what i'm tying to clean up.  Do you have something specific in mind for the "somewhere else completely" ?

Comment: Why does it have to end up with big if/elseif blocks? Can't you abstract that? As you have it now, you just move that complexity somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think i should be using selectors, or something else rather than hardcoding the fact that the caller (delegator?) needs to implement -didGetCalledBack: Right? IF so, how? (and why, other than cleanliness)

Nothing wrong with what you are doing.  You might want to consider declaring a protocol for a calling object e.g.

```
@protocol CallingObject <NSObject>
    -(void) didGetCallBack: (NSArray*) resultArray;
@end
```

And then

```
@interface Model : NSObject <CallingObject> // ...
```

and

```
@interface MyConnectionDelegate : NSObject
{
    // ...
}

-(id) initWithCallingObject: (id<CallingObject>) calller;

// ...

@end
```

That will give you some compile time checking that the calling object implements the required method(s).

Comment: Ah yes, that's a good idea - I was wondering how to get rid of that compile warning. (Now I've come to learn that warnings are really bad, unlike previous languages i've worked in where warnings are just bad ;))

Answer (score 1):

> Maybe i should have delegate:self too for the `NSURLConnection`, but I'm making many connections and if i do `delegate:self` my delegate methods (like `-didReceiveData:`) become a big mess of `if (connection ==connection1){` type code.

Then don't use explicit comparisons - use containers or similar abstractions to react to different connections.

E.g. to use the results of connections with different controls, use a dictionary that maps from `NSURLConnection`s to those controls so the following:

```
if      (connection == connection1) [obj1 doStuff];
else if (connection == connection2) [obj2 doStuff];
// ...
```

becomes:

```
[[connectionClients objectForKey:connection] doStuff];
```